# Neo4j on PARALLEL runtime returns different results (different elements order) compared to SLOTTED or PIPELINED

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-parallel-runtime

I am testing the new Neo4j PARALLEL runtime and am unable to pass my tests because my queries return different results (different element order) compared to SLOTTED or PIPELINED.

For example, in the following query, the result is dancing all of the time:

```
CYPHER runtime = parallel
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {
  id: -2
})-[rdgd: CONTAINS ]-> ( childD:Profile )
MATCH (childD)-[mhvo:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(mc:Criterion)
WHERE mc.id IN [9760, 9761, 9757, 9758, 9759] + []
WITH childD , collect(mhvo) AS mhvos
WHERE size(mhvos) >= size([9760, 9761, 9757, 9758, 9759])
WITH childD
WHERE (childD.`active` = true )
WITH childD
WITH childD
MATCH (childDStat:JobableStatistic {
  jobableId: childD.id
})
WITH childD, childDStat
UNWIND [9760, 9761, 9757, 9758, 9759] AS dCId
WITH childD, childDStat, dCId + coalesce({}[toString(dCId)], []) AS cGroup
WHERE NOT AlL(x IN cGroup
WHERE x IN childDStat.zeroCriterionIds )
WITH childD, childDStat, collect(cGroup) AS cGroups
WHERE size(cGroups) >= size([9760, 9761, 9757, 9758, 9759])
UNWIND cGroups AS cGroup
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroup
WHERE ANY(x IN cGroup
WHERE x IN childDStat.detailedCriterionIds)
WITH childD, childDStat, collect(cGroup) AS cGroups
WHERE size(cGroups) >= size([9760, 9761, 9757, 9758, 9759])
WITH childD, childDStat, size(cGroups) AS cGroupsSize, cGroups
UNWIND cGroups AS cGroup
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroups, cGroupsSize, cGroup
UNWIND cGroup AS cId
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroups, cGroupsSize, cGroup, cId, cGroup[0] AS cG0
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroups, cGroupsSize, cGroup, cId, cG0, {
  `9759`:1.0, `9758`:1.0, `9760`:1.0, `9761`:1.0, `9757`:1.0
}[toString(cG0)] AS criterionAvgVoteWeight, {
  `9759`:0, `9758`:0, `9760`:0, `9761`:0, `9757`:0
}[toString(cG0)] AS criterionExperienceMonth
WHERE (criterionAvgVoteWeight = 0 OR criterionAvgVoteWeight <= childDStat['criterionAvgVoteWeights.' + cId]) AND (criterionExperienceMonth = 0 OR criterionExperienceMonth <= childDStat['criterionExperienceMonths.' + cId])
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroups, cGroupsSize, collect(cId) AS cIds
UNWIND cGroups AS cGroup
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroup, cGroupsSize, cIds
WHERE ANY(x IN cIds
WHERE x IN cGroup)
WITH childD, childDStat, cGroupsSize, collect(cGroup) AS cGroups
WHERE size(cGroups) >= cGroupsSize
WITH childD, childDStat
UNWIND [9760, 9761, 9757, 9758, 9759] AS cId
WITH childD, childDStat, cId, {
  `9759`:1.0, `9758`:1.0, `9760`:1.0, `9761`:1.0, `9757`:1.0
}[toString(cId)] AS criterionCoefficient
WITH childD, sum(criterionCoefficient * childDStat['criterionAvgVoteWeights.' + cId]) AS weight, sum(childDStat['criterionTotalVotes.' + cId]) AS totalVotes, sum(criterionCoefficient) AS criterionCoefficientSum
WITH childD, weight, totalVotes, criterionCoefficientSum
WITH collect({`childD`:childD , `weight`:weight, `totalVotes`: totalVotes }) AS aggregate
WITH aggregate, size(aggregate) AS count
UNWIND aggregate AS item
WITH count, item.childD AS childD , item.weight AS weight, item.totalVotes AS totalVotes
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {
  id: -2
})-[rdgd: CONTAINS ]->(childD)
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (jobable:Decision:Vacancy {
  id: 4928
})
RETURN count, childD AS decision, dg, rdgd , u, ru , jobable.id AS jobableId , weight, totalVotes, [ (jobable)-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion) | {
  criterion: c1, relationship: vg1
} ] AS jobableWeightedCriteria, [(jobable)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD)
WHERE c1.id IN childD.detailedCriterionIds | {
  criterion: c1, relationship: vg1
} ] AS weightedCriteria , [ (c1t:Translation:BaseEntity)<-[rc1t: CONTAINS ]-(c1:Criterion)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD)
WHERE EXISTS ((jobable)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1)) AND c1t.iso6391 = 'uk' AND c1.id IN childD.detailedCriterionIds | {
  entityId: toInteger(c1.id), translation: c1t
} ] AS weightedCriteriaTranslations , [ (jobable)-[:WORK_LOCATED_IN|EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_AS|READY_TO|EMPLOYMENT_AS|WORK_TIME_ZONE|BELONGS_TO|LOCATED_IN|COMPANY|WORK_PERMIT_IN|COMPANY_TYPE_OF]->(ce:CompositeEntity) | {
  entity: ce
} ] AS jobableCompositeEntities, [ (childD)-[:WORK_LOCATED_IN|EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_AS|READY_TO|EMPLOYMENT_AS|WORK_TIME_ZONE|BELONGS_TO|LOCATED_IN|COMPANY|WORK_PERMIT_IN|COMPANY_TYPE_OF]->(ce:CompositeEntity) | {
  entity: ce
} ] AS decisionCompositeEntities, [ (childD)-[:WORK_LOCATED_IN|EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_AS|READY_TO|EMPLOYMENT_AS|WORK_TIME_ZONE|BELONGS_TO|LOCATED_IN|COMPANY|WORK_PERMIT_IN|COMPANY_TYPE_OF]->(ce:CompositeEntity)-[: CONTAINS ]->(trans:Translation:BaseEntity)
WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {
  entityId: toInteger(id(ce)), translation: trans
} ] AS decisionCompositeEntitiesTranslations, [ (childD)-[: CONTAINS ]->(trans:Translation:BaseEntity)
WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {
  entityId: toInteger(childD.id), translation: trans
} ] AS decisionTranslations, [ (rc:Criterion)-[*0]->()
WHERE rc.id IN childD.replaceableCriterionIds | {
  entity: rc
} ] AS decisionReplaceableCriteria, [ (rc:Criterion)-[: CONTAINS ]->(trans:Translation:BaseEntity)
WHERE rc.id IN childD.replaceableCriterionIds AND trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {
  entityId: toInteger(id(rc)), translation: trans
} ] AS decisionReplaceableCriteriaTranslations, COUNT {
  (:Vacancy:Jobable:BaseEntity {status: 'APPROVED', active: true
})<-[:POTENTIAL_PROFILE]-(childD) } AS potentialJobablesCount , COUNT {
  (:Vacancy:Jobable:BaseEntity {status: 'APPROVED', active: true
})<-[:RELEVANT_PROFILE]-(childD) } AS relevantJobablesCount 

ORDER BY weight DESC, childD.createdAt DESC SKIP 0
LIMIT 100
```

When executed multiple times, this query returns records in arbitrary order with varying weights. One time weight=25 is on the first place.. another time - weight=10 on the first place. What could be the cause of this?

With `CYPHER runtime = pipelined` this query is working fine.

I may be wrong, but it looks like the pattern comprehensive or COUNT subquery somehow affects the query ordering, specifically this part:

```
, [ (jobable)-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion) | {
  criterion: c1, relationship: vg1
} ] AS jobableWeightedCriteria, [(jobable)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD)
WHERE c1.id IN childD.detailedCriterionIds | {
  criterion: c1, relationship: vg1
} ] AS weightedCriteria , [ (c1t:Translation:BaseEntity)<-[rc1t: CONTAINS ]-(c1:Criterion)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD)
WHERE EXISTS ((jobable)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1)) AND c1t.iso6391 = 'uk' AND c1.id IN childD.detailedCriterionIds | {
  entityId: toInteger(c1.id), translation: c1t
} ] AS weightedCriteriaTranslations , [ (jobable)-[:WORK_LOCATED_IN|EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_AS|READY_TO|EMPLOYMENT_AS|WORK_TIME_ZONE|BELONGS_TO|LOCATED_IN|COMPANY|WORK_PERMIT_IN|COMPANY_TYPE_OF]->(ce:CompositeEntity) | {
  entity: ce
} ] AS jobableCompositeEntities, [ (childD)-[:WORK_LOCATED_IN|EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_AS|READY_TO|EMPLOYMENT_AS|WORK_TIME_ZONE|BELONGS_TO|LOCATED_IN|COMPANY|WORK_PERMIT_IN|COMPANY_TYPE_OF]->(ce:CompositeEntity) | {
  entity: ce
} ] AS decisionCompositeEntities, [ (childD)-[:WORK_LOCATED_IN|EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_AS|READY_TO|EMPLOYMENT_AS|WORK_TIME_ZONE|BELONGS_TO|LOCATED_IN|COMPANY|WORK_PERMIT_IN|COMPANY_TYPE_OF]->(ce:CompositeEntity)-[: CONTAINS ]->(trans:Translation:BaseEntity)
WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {
  entityId: toInteger(id(ce)), translation: trans
} ] AS decisionCompositeEntitiesTranslations, [ (childD)-[: CONTAINS ]->(trans:Translation:BaseEntity)
WHERE trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {
  entityId: toInteger(childD.id), translation: trans
} ] AS decisionTranslations, [ (rc:Criterion)-[*0]->()
WHERE rc.id IN childD.replaceableCriterionIds | {
  entity: rc
} ] AS decisionReplaceableCriteria, [ (rc:Criterion)-[: CONTAINS ]->(trans:Translation:BaseEntity)
WHERE rc.id IN childD.replaceableCriterionIds AND trans.iso6391 = 'uk' | {
  entityId: toInteger(id(rc)), translation: trans
} ] AS decisionReplaceableCriteriaTranslations, COUNT {
  (:Vacancy:Jobable:BaseEntity {status: 'APPROVED', active: true
})<-[:POTENTIAL_PROFILE]-(childD) } AS potentialJobablesCount , COUNT {
  (:Vacancy:Jobable:BaseEntity {status: 'APPROVED', active: true
})<-[:RELEVANT_PROFILE]-(childD) } AS relevantJobablesCount
```

How to make the query working correctly on Neo4j PARALLEL runtime?

Comment: If the parallel runtime does not always return results in the specified order, that sounds like a bug and I see that you already opened an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/13382).